# Pubnub Publish and Subscribe key

Tags: pubnub

I am new to PubNub.com.

My problem is, when I give `publish_key` and `subscribe_key` as `demo`, my application works fine.

But when I give my original `publish_key` and `subscribe_key`, it stuck in a infinite loop.

Please help !

Comment: Gonna need more details to troubleshoot. What SDK/version? Any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I solved this problem.
I accidentally erase some code, which was causing problem.

Comment: Can you provide your root cause as official answer?